# decodeURI not replacing &amp; with &

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using decodeURI on a Vue project I'm working on. Though, the API I'm utilising (Reddit) it returning encoded URL's for their images. decodeURI is working to an extent, but it is not replacing `&amp;` with the correct `&`.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
<img :src="decodeURI(post.data.preview.images[0].source.url)" :alt=post.data.title />
```

Comment: In percent-encoding, a literal `&` is represented by `%26`. `decodeURI` will replace `%26` with `&`. By contrast, `&amp;` is an HTML-escape for `&`.

Comment: `&amp;` is an HTML entity, not a URL-encoded value.

Answer (score 0):

The `decodeURI()` function decodes what `encodeURI()` encodes.

Since `&` will not be encoded by `encodeURI()`, `decodeURI()` won't decode `&amp;`.

```js
console.log(encodeURI("&"));
```